# JQuery struggling to get value from radio button

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form like so

```
 <form>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="yes" checked="checked">Yes</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="no">No</label><br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn artBtn" title="click here ">Submit &gt;</button>
</form>
```

This form is used across several pages, but I dont think that should matter.
I then do the following

```
$(".artBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('input[name="optradio"]:checked').size() > 0) {
        $('.contentDiv').html('<p>Thanks!</p>');
        submitData($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Why would the value I send to submitData be empty?  I have tried retrieving it directly though the input as well, but if I do this it is undefined.  How can I get the appropriate selected value?

Thanks

Comment: You are sending the value of the button pressed! (and it does not have a value) :)

Comment: [`.size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/) is also deprecated in favor of `.length`

Comment: The answer I chose was top of the list - seems like you both answered at the same time.

Comment: Hover over the answered times for the *exact* times. :) Thanks for correcting. The display orders depend on what sorting you selected. Select "oldest" to get the order they were submitted.

Comment: P.S. Your accept just got me the silver "epic" badge.+1 to say thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a `click` handler, `this` refers to the element clicked. That means you are sending the value of the submit `button` pressed. As it has no value you are getting a blank sent.

Send the value of the selected radio button instead:

```
submitData($('input[name="optradio"]:checked').val());
```

So the full version might go like this:

```
$(".artBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $radio = $('input[name="optradio"]:checked');
    if ($radio.length){
        $('.contentDiv').html('<p>Thanks!</p>');
        submitData($radio.val());
    }
});
```

### Notes:

- You can just test for a non-zero length with `if ($radio.length)` to see if there was a match.
- Only run selectors once, to avoid extra processing and save the result in a variable.
- I promote the standard of prefixing jQuery objects with `$` to make it obvious what is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on what @TrueBlueAussie said, in the scope of your `click` event, `$(this)` is going to refer to the button itself. To fix this, you could assign the radio button to a variable, and just reference it later, like this

```
$(".artBtn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $radio = $('input[name="optradio"]:checked');
  if ($radio.size() > 0) {
    $('.contentDiv').html('<p>Thanks!</p>');
    submitData($radio.val());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `this` as if it is the radiobutton that is checked. This works within events, as the reference to the element that caused the event to trigger. Here this lives within the click event that is caused by clicking the artBtn button, so this holds the reference to the button. Clearly your button does not hold value, so that's why you're getting no results.

If you want to get the  value of the radiobutton, try this:

```
$(".artBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var radio = ($('input[name="optradio"]:checked');
    if(radio.length > 0)
    {
         $('.contentDiv').html('<p>Thanks!</p>');
         submitData(radio.val());
    }
});
```